# How can I replace each occurence of a specifc letter with a word from an array

Tags: java

Im basically just trying to replace the character '$' with words that I have in this array.
I also want it so that every time that character appears, it goes to the next word in the array.

Example:

Array = ("BEAR", "RICE", "STEAK")

String = "He$$$llo"

Output: HeBEARRICESTEAKllo

AS you can see, it goes down sequentially through the array.

This is the code I have.

```
    private static String[] stickers= {"PUMPKIN", "BAT", "WITCH", "BAT"};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count=0;
        char search = '$';
        String data_type,data,replacedata,updated_data;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("What type of data?");
            data_type=scan.nextLine();
            String updated_datatype = data_type.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","");
            System.out.println("Type your message: ");
            data=scan.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
                if(data.charAt(i)==search)
                    count++;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
                updated_data = data.replace("$", stickers[j]);
                System.out.println("Your updated message is: "+updated_data);
            }
            //System.out.println("Your word: "+data+" ,has this many occurances of $: "+count);
            //replacedata=data.replace('$', replacement'')

            //if (data_type=="name");

        }while(data_type!="exit");
    }
```

All this does for me is replace the all the characters with the element thats being iterated through the array.

Also, as you can tell, im fairly new to java and programming overall. Thanks!!

Comment: It would be better if you gave an example which just uses static data instead of including your user input code in the question, as that isn't the part you're asking about.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the count of `$` doesn’t match the array length?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static Pattern PAT = Pattern.compile("\\$");

static String replaceWords(String s, String[] stickers) {
    Iterator<String> i = Arrays.stream(stickers).iterator();
    return PAT.matcher(s).replaceAll(m -> i.next());
}
```

and

```
String[] stickers= {"BEAR", "RICE", "STEAK"};
String s = "He$$$llo";
System.out.println(replaceWords(s, stickers));
```

output:

```
HeBEARRICESTEAKllo
```

Comment: This is def on my end but I keep getting a cannot find symbol error right at Iterator<String>

Answer (score 0):

Acquire the number of tags ("$") that need to be changed then iterate based on that number and sequentially change those tags with array elements. In the following method code, any number of tags can be supplied in any size of string. The tags will be sequentially changed based on what is contained as string elements within the supplied String[] Array.

Read the comments in code:

```
/**
 * This method will replace all of a specific string character tag encountered 
 * within a supplied string sequentially with a string element contained within 
 * the supplied String[] Array. 
 * <p>
 * <b>Example Usage:</b><pre>
 * 
 *    String[] array = {"BEAR", "RICE", "STEAK"};
 *    String inputString = "He$$$ll$o Th$$er$e";
 *    String modifiedString = replaceTagsWithArrayElements(inputString, "$", array);
 *    System.out.println(modifiedString);
 * 
 * With the above example, the Console Window will display:
 * 
 *    HeBEARRICESTEAKllBEARo ThRICESTEAKerBEARe</pre>
 * 
 * @param inputString (String) The supplied string to replace tags in. If 
 * null or an empty string is supplied then the same is returned.<br>
 * 
 * @param tag (String) The tag within the string which needs to be sequentially 
 * replaced with supplied String[] array elements. The tag can only be a single 
 * character. If null or an empty string is supplied then an IllegalArumentException 
 * is thrown.<br>
 * 
 * @param replacementArray (String[] Array) The supplied String[] Array which 
 * contains the strings that each encountered tag will be sequentially replaced 
 * with. If the supplied array is null or contains a length of 0 then an 
 * IllegalArumentException is thrown.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) The modified input string.
 */
public static String replaceTagsWithArrayElements(String inputString, 
                         String tag, String[] replacementArray) {
    // Validate Parameters..
    if (inputString == null || inputString.isEmpty()) { 
        return inputString; 
    }
    else if (tag == null || tag.length() > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("replaceTagsWithArrayElements() "
                + "Method Error! Invalid Tag (" + tag + ") Supplied!");
    }
    else if (replacementArray.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("replaceTagsWithArrayElements() "
                + "Method Error! The supplied String[] Array is empty!");
    }
    
    // Keep the supplied string intact. Use a worker variable (strg).
    String strg = inputString;
    
    // See how many tags are contained within the supplied input string.
    int numOfSigns = strg.replaceAll("[^" + tag +"]", "").length();
    
    int ii = 0;  // index counter to supply String[] array element Strings
    
    // Iterate based on the number of tags...
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSigns; i++) {
        /* If the array index counter exceeds the length 
           of the array then reset the counter to 0.  */
        if (ii > replacementArray.length -1) { 
            ii = 0; 
        }
        // Change the current Tag with the current array element.
        strg = strg.substring(0, strg.indexOf("$")) 
                + replacementArray[ii] + strg.substring(strg.indexOf("$") + 1);
        ii++;  // Increment the array index counter by 1.
    }
    
    return strg;   // Return the modified input string.
}
```

To use the above method, you might do this:

```
String[] array = {"BEAR", "RICE", "STEAK"};
String inputString = "He$$$ll$o Th$$er$e";
String modifiedString = replaceTagsWithArrayElements(inputString, "$", array);
System.out.println(modifiedString);
```

The Console Window should display:

```
HeBEARRICESTEAKllBEARo ThRICESTEAKerBEARe
```

Comment: This is beyond perfect, thanks a lot for the help